# R plotly x axis numerical date conversion back to real date

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

can anyone help me with this. I had a ggplot where the values in the x-axis are dates. I've converted to a plotly plot using ggplotly. When I use box select or lasso select on my plotly plot the x-axis values are being picked up as numerical dates. I give some of them here
event$x <- c(149653440000, 149662080000, 149679360000)
converting these back to dates doenst work by simply applying as.Date. I've read alot of answers to similar question where as.Date.POSIXct is used but that doesnt work with my dates. Can anyone give help on how to convert these numerical numbers back to real dates?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question now. Plotly is reading my dates in in javascript milliseconds. To covert to a date divide by 1000 by 60 by 60 and by 24 then use as.Date to convert that number back to a date. Basically do the opposite of whats shown in the solution shown here: 
https://community.plot.ly/t/manual-date-range-on-x-axis-time-series/1316/2